# Getting a socket error when trying to connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, debian, lamp

I updated my Linode server from Debian 8 to 11, and this has caused multiple issues. I'm aware this was a very silly thing to do, and I didn't even have any real backup strategy.

But anyway, I'm setting up a new Linode and trying to migrate everything over. I need to get a backup of my MySQL database, but when I try to access MySQL, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

This command:

```
sudo find / -type s | grep mysql
```

returns nothing. So it looks like there is no socket file present. I have confirmed that MySQL is in fact running, by entering:

```
systemctl status mysql
```

The output is:

```
? mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2021-12-02 14:25:19 GMT; 18min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 2643 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=0/SUCC>
        CPU: 2ms

Dec 02 14:25:19 odaiba systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the mysql datab>
Dec 02 14:25:19 odaiba systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the mysql databa>
lines 1-9/9 (END)
```

I ran this command:

```
cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

which returned the following output:

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 0. "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" symlinks to this file, reason why all the rest is read.
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# If you are new to MariaDB, check out https://mariadb.com/kb/en/basic-mariadb-/

#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
# port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

There is no /run/mysqld directory. I created it, and restarted MySQL, but this seemed to make no difference. I'm not sure how to set this my.cnf file to properly define or create the socket.

I'm also a little confused about all the references to MariaDB. Could that be something to do with the issue?

Any help at all is hugely appreciated!!

Comment: Sometimes mysql's socket connection has root-only permissions in recent distros. Try running your backup as root. Or try using `-h 127.0.0.1` to connect to it with TCP instead of the socket.

Comment: I've tried running as root, but no change. I've also tried using ```-h 127.0.0.1``` but I just get the following:
```ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)```